# Why was this post auto-flagged?

Tags: support, review

https://security.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/116392

It says it was flagged because of length **and** content, but I doubt that: the post has seven downvotes (fairly unusual here) and the content is normal English. The post also doesn't look that short to me (550 chars text, without markdown; other posts of <250 chars are not flagged).

Is that message on top completely static, regardless of the true reason it was auto-flagged (which I suspect is downvotes)? Because then I know to completely ignore it when using that review queue.

Comment: I ignore the message on the top, since I don't find it very useful. But maybe thats a bad strategy I use?

Answer (score 6):

It was not auto-flagged but flagged by users.

Comment: Can only ♦moderators see that?

Comment: As a mod, I don't know what non mods can see

Comment: Well, where do you see what the flags were... can you see it in the link I posted? Or is there a link you could post here, which I could try if it works (or see if I have some button in my UI)?

Comment: I can see it in the answers timeline. I'm not sure what permissions you need to see the timeline.

Comment: Yes, this is a mod-only feature showing who flagged a post, when, and why. A person flagged it so it went to the view queue, and it was simultaneously passed through the moderator queue.